# R: new column names in data frame and integration of the original columnames as part of the data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="1 0 0 1
                1 0 1 1
                1 0 0 0
                1 1 1 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 1 0
                3 0 1 1
                3 0 0 1
                3 0 0 1")
```

I want to bring the column names as part of the data and create a column name such as V1, V2, V3 and V4:

```
df_new <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="V1 V2 V3 V4
                1 0 0 1
                1 0 1 1
                1 0 0 0
                1 1 1 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 1 0
                3 0 1 1
                3 0 0 1
                3 0 0 1")
```

Comment: Why not just read in the first table with ``header=F``? This seems like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: If you check `df` it has column names as `X1 X0 X0.1 X1.1`. Can you confirm if that is the also the case in your actual data ?

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. True, I just noticed that the column names are ```X1 X0 X0.1 X1.1```. In case they were the numbers specified in the data? is there a way to place those numbers as observations and get the column names as V1,.... V4. @Zoe, I know one could just read the table using header=FALSE but I am reading the actual table with another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in your actual case you have data like this -

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="1 0 0 1
                1 0 1 1
                1 0 0 0
                1 1 1 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 0 0
                2 1 1 0
                3 0 1 1
                3 0 0 1
                3 0 0 1", check.names = FALSE)
```

You can make the column names as first row by -

```
rbind(t(as.numeric(names(df))), setNames(df, paste0('V', seq_along(df))))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1   1  0  0  1
#2   1  0  1  1
#3   1  0  0  0
#4   1  1  1  0
#5   2  1  0  0
#6   2  1  0  0
#7   2  1  1  0
#8   3  0  1  1
#9   3  0  0  1
#10  3  0  0  1
```